# How to copy specific columns from one sheet and paste in another sheet in a different range?

Tags: vba, excel, basic

I am a beginner and I have this code below, but this just copies the last row from sheet and pastes into sheet 2 range. Basically the empty row is not getting updated. And also throws run time error 1004 - Application defined or object defined error. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub copypaste()
Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long

lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow

Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Copy
erow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 2)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 14).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 4)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 3)

Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Columns().AutoFit
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Lets say this is sheet 1
 [sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZRUM.png)

and this is sheet2:
[sheet2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV3F4.png)

Where the headers are slightly different in naming and there's also a position change. And the last row in sheet 1 is varied.

Comment: You have explained what the code does, can you explain what it is you want it to do. An example of the desired outcome would be helpful also.

Comment: @tim:  What i want to is copy column 3 from Sheet 1 paste in column 2 of sheet 2, copy column 14 from sheet 1 and paste in column 4 of sheet 2 ..etc. And i want to do the same without copying the headers from both sheets. Finally when i run the macro, i want data to be copied from sheet 1 to sheet 2, WITHOUT headers and in a DIFFERENT region. Hope this helps

Comment: @TimWilkinson i have edited the question and added details too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, always better to avoid copy and paste.

```
Sub copypaste()
Dim lastrow As Integer, erow As Integer, sheet1 As Worksheet, sheet2 As Worksheet

Set sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
lastrow = sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    erow = sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    sheet2.Cells(erow, 2) = sheet1.Cells(i, 3)
    sheet2.Cells(erow, 3) = sheet1.Cells(i, 6)
    sheet2.Cells(erow, 4) = sheet1.Cells(i, 14)
Next i

'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns().AutoFit
'sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: This is still giving me Run time error 1004 -Application defined or object defined error..

Comment: I just commented out the last two lines out of curiosity can you try with the new code and see if it still happens?

Comment: Its working.. :) Thanks a lot.. But am curious to know how.

Comment: I noticed it was happening a few times on mine for just the very last "Range("A1").Select" and I have to be honest I have no idea! If this answer is working please don't forget to mark as accepted.